# Add positive sign in Kendo NumericTextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I have a Kendo NumericTextBox. This text box allows positive and negative numbers.

As expected, negative numbers have a '-' prefix.

Is it possible to prefix a '+' on positive numbers?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5. Here's a code sample:

```
@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.PositveNegative).Step(0.25f)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Abrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Mr Cocococo's answer as a starting point here is the MVC wrapper version for you:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox().Name("Test").Step(0.25f)
.Events(events => events.Change("Testing").Spin("Testing"))
  )




    <script>

        function Testing()
        {

            var numeric = $("#Test").val();

            if (numeric > 0)
            {
                $("#Test").kendoNumericTextBox({ format: "+##.##", decimals: 2 });
            }
            else
            {
                $("#Test").kendoNumericTextBox({ format: "##.##", decimals: 2 });

            }
            console.log(numeric);
        }

    </script>
```

This works with either typing or using the spinners and should give you the desired results.

Comment: This worked for me. I really appreciate your and @mr-cocococo 's help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Change and Spin event handler.
Here are the code in javascript version.

```
$("#inputID").kendoNumericTextBox({
                        format: "+#",
                        change: function() {
                          var value = this.value();                             
                          if(value>0) this.options.format="+#";
                          else this.options.format="#";

                        },
                       spin: function() {
                          var value = this.value();
                          if(value>0) this.options.format="+#";
                          else this.options.format="#";
                      }
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the code sample. It adds a + for positive numbers. However, there's one issue, the negative numbers also get the + prefix. 
<script>
    function change() {
        $("#PositveNegative").kendoNumericTextBox({
            format: "+#.##",
            change: function() {
                var value = this.value();            
                if(value > 0) 
                {
                    this.options.format="+#.##";
                }
                else 
                {
                    this.options.format="#.##";
                }
            }
        });   
    }

Comment: add handler for "spin" as well

Comment: Apologies, let me clarify. I used your example with the spin handler. I still get the same issue in that if I type into the NumericTextBox or use the up down arrows, the negative values show as +-0.25, +-0.5, +-0.75, etc. I put an alert(value) in the else clause and I get the desired result -0.25. It's as if the format in not being applied. Do you any other suggestions? I appreciate your help.